# Can I ask a non-academic for an academic letter of recommendation?

Tags: funding, recommendation-letter, undergraduate

A scholarship based on existing mental health problems and conviction to finishing/doing well in school and it requests 2 reference letters and doesn't specify from whom. I'm only a second year in my undergrad, and all of my classes are too big for a connection with a professor. There is no one academic to write me one.

My mom suggested this one family friend who is a nurse and who has known me for 14 years. Is this a good idea? Any ideas who could write the second one?

Comment: Could you check the program materials to see if they give some advice on what sort of reference letter is needed, or perhaps there is some material intended for letter-writers that instructs them what should be covered/addressed? With some tips for that we could maybe give more useful advice. If this were a letter for graduate school admission in the US this would be relatively easy to answer - but in the case of such a scholarship its really totally up to the issuing organization what they would like to see.

Comment: Unfortunately not, there is no information provided. It is the Sarah Gaulin scholarship if that helps at all? 
Really, I think it is supposed to showcase our ongoing struggle with mental health issues and our perseverance in academics

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of such letters is to get some assurance from "trusted" commentators who can attest to the likelihood of your success in the program. While for most academic letters, professors and teachers are best, in this case it may be different. I can't suggest who would be best, but keep the two elements in mind:

People who can be immediately trusted to give an honest assessment, and people who can judge your likelihood of success.

Answer (score 1):

> My mom suggested this one family friend who is a nurse and who has known me for 14 years. Is this a good idea?

Does this nurse know anything about your professional/academic life? Has she "seen you in action"? Is she familiar with your mental health struggles and commitment to finishing school? If so, it's maybe okay for now. If this is just a friend of your moms who happens to be a nurse and knows little about you, then this is a bad idea.

In general, letters of recommendation should be commenting on how you stack up next to your peers, and should be written by someone who has seen many many students and can judge how you rank next to them. Though for this particular scholarship you mention, I agree it doesn't say at all whether this is the case or whether they want someone who can comment on your "personal narrative", including your mental health.

> Any ideas who could write the second one?

Consider your professors or TAs. Just send them a three-sentence e-mail, or drop by their office hours. You'd be surprised how accommodating some professors will be, if you make it clear that you appreciate the favor and don't expect anything more than a brief letter saying that you took their class and got an decent grade. Since you're in the middle of college, even a nice letter from a TA might be sufficient for one of your letters. And of course, start working now so you don't have this problem when it's time for graduate school admissions or job recommendations!